# BlueData MLOPS - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: bluedata, mlops

I've created a MLOPS project on BlueData 4.0 and mounted the Project Repo (NFS) folder.  I created the NFS service on Centos 7x as below:

```
  sudo yum -y install nfs-utils
  sudo mkdir /nfsroot
  echo '/nfsroot *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)' | sudo tee /etc/exports
  sudo exportfs -r
  sudo systemctl enable nfs-server.service
  sudo systemctl start nfs-server.service
```

I'm now trying to access a data set stored in the NFS Project Repo, but I'm receiving the following error:

> `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/bd-fs-mnt/path/data.csv'`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the project repo is created with root as owner and no write permissions on group level.

To fix, you need to:

- create a notebook cluster
- open a Jupyter Terminal
- `sudo chmod -R 777 /bd-fs-mnt/nfsrepo` (this only works if you create that cluster as tenant admin, as user you don't have sudo permission)